# Updating a module in the Raku Ecosystem

Tags: raku, zef, rakubrew

It's been a while since I last updated one of my modules in the Raku ecosystem. Do I need to update a central registry file/repo or will the update be automatically detected?

Comment: I've only ever just updated my META6.json file, but not told zef about it.  Ultimately, most of the work is done client side when installing (the ecosystem just lets zef know that the module exists and where to find it)

Comment: Not really. They get indexed by zef automatically, so if you upgrade your version it will get detected. You will need to update the ecosystem, however, if you need several versions to be available.

Answer (score 3):

After I bumped the version number I waited for an hour or so and then `zef` could install the module - thanks fo the comments above. It looks like the ecosystem automatically picks up changes.

Comment: That sounds like a good answer to your question. It is perfectly legitimate to answer your own questions and accept your answer. I don't wish to be pushy, but I encourage you to accept your answer, to create clarity and closure for later readers, or to consider explaining why you think your answer isn't really acceptable, to encourage later answerers.